# Ruby model search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to implement a search feature on my application and I'm wondering what would be the best approach.

I have a Player model with 2 boolean columns (three,five) <-- name of columns
and I'm trying to fetch them for visualization depending on either the columns are true or false. ( Displaying all threes or all fives )

Should I create controllers for each of them or I should define them in the Player Controller ?

As for the Model, the best way to search for them would be like this ?

```
players = Player.all
players.find_by three: true
```

or there is a more elegant way ?

Comment: Take a look at this [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/111-advanced-search-form).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your scenario gets more complicated break out a query object.  Until then, this will get you close.  Then in your params all you have to do is set query to either 'three' or 'five' to get the players of that type.

```
class Player
  scope :by_three -> where(three: true)}
  scope :by_five  -> where(five: true)}
end

def index
  if params[:query] == 'three'
    @players = Player.by_three
  elsif params[:query] == 'five'
    @players = Player.by_five
  end
end
```